# state object is not getting set in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to set state of updatedResponse object, but is not setting it. I have printed to console the object that Im trying to set it with, and that is getting populated but for some reason the updatedResponse variable is not being set. here is my code:

```
const [updatedResponse, setUpdatedResponse] = useState({});
  const [updatedResponseComplete, setUpdatedResponseComplete] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {

    console.log("print api response", apiResponse)
    let respObj= {}


    console.log("print updated response", updatedResponse)

    let len = Object.keys(response?.Products).length

    if(Object.keys(apiResponse).length > 0){

      Object.keys(response?.Products).forEach((key, ind) => {
        if(response?.Products[key].PRODUCT_CODE === apiResponse.Products?.PRODUCT_1.PRODUCT_CODE){

          console.log("true")
          const updatedProd = {...apiResponse.Products?.PRODUCT_1,
          PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION: apiResponse.Products?.PRODUCT_1.PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION + " Simulation " + (panels.length + 1)}

          console.log("print updated prod", updatedProd)
          respObj[key] =response.Products[key]
          respObj['PRODUCT_' + (len + 1)]= updatedProd
        }
        else{
          respObj[key] =response.Products[key]
        }
      })
  
      console.log("print resp obj", respObj)
      console.log("print updated response", updatedResponse)

      
      // console.log({...response, Products: respObj})
      setUpdatedResponseComplete(true)
      setUpdatedResponse({...response, Products: respObj});
    

    }

    // console.log(updatedResponseComplete)
   
    
      
  }, [apiResponse]);
```

the updatedResponseComplete is getting set to true, but the updatedResponse is coming as an empty object {Products:{}} can someone help me debug it thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### It is *asynchronous*, remember

Try using the `useEffect` hook to pick up the result once it is ready.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("updated response", updatedResponse);
}, [updatedResponse]);
```